Vuetify Sparkline with long x-axis but keep height the same
Vuetify 2.  I am trying to make a Sparkline with a very long x-axis, so I want it to have a horizontal scrollbar (otherwise the labels are unreadable).  I also want it to be inside a Sheet (so that I can eventually overlay other lines).
Normally to force a horizontal scrollbar I would have something with a large width inside a DIV with "overflow-x: auto".  But when I make the Sheet or Sparkline width large, the height of the chart increases as well, as if it has a built-in size ratio.  Also the line becomes much thicker.
Any ideas please?  Thanks.
https://codepen.io/hobbeschild/pen/QWRgeKv
Try playing with the Sheet or Sparkline width in this codepen.
I am trying to get a very wide chart that remains a short height.
    <div id="app">
      <v-app id="inspire">
        <div style="overflow-x: auto;">
          <v-sheet width="1000">
            <v-sparkline
              :value="value"
              line-width="1"
            ></v-sparkline>
            </v-sheet>
        </div>
      </v-app>
    </div>

    new Vue({
      el: '#app',
      vuetify: new Vuetify(),
      data: () => ({
        value: [0, 2, 5, 9, 5, 10, 3, 5, 0, 0, 1, 8, 2, 9, 0, 0, 2, 5, 9, 5, 10, 3, 5, 0, 0, 1, 8, 2, 9, 0, 0, 2, 5, 9, 5, 10, 3, 5, 0, 0, 1, 8, 2, 9, 0, 0, 2, 5, 9, 5, 10, 3, 5, 0, 0, 1, 8, 2, 9, 0],
      }),
    })


The answer was to give the Sparkline a height.
Although, this made the line hugely thick, so I had to make the line width 0.1 to compensate.
    <div id="app">
      <v-app id="inspire">
        <div style="overflow-x: auto;">
          <v-sheet width="1000">
            <v-sparkline
              :value="value"
              line-width="0.1"
              height="10"
            ></v-sparkline>
            </v-sheet>
        </div>
      </v-app>
    </div>

    new Vue({
      el: '#app',
      vuetify: new Vuetify(),
      data: () => ({
        value: [0, 2, 5, 9, 5, 10, 3, 5, 0, 0, 1, 8, 2, 9, 0, 0, 2, 5, 9, 5, 10, 3, 5, 0, 0, 1, 8, 2, 9, 0, 0, 2, 5, 9, 5, 10, 3, 5, 0, 0, 1, 8, 2, 9, 0, 0, 2, 5, 9, 5, 10, 3, 5, 0, 0, 1, 8, 2, 9, 0],
      }),
    })

